# Limit min and max Length (character input ) in MaskedTextBox mask

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I need to configure the `Mask` property of a MaskedTextBox to take in a password that meets the following criteria:

- Minimum of 4 alphanumeric characters
- Maximum of 15 alphanumeric    characters

I have tried setting the mask to the string "aaaa" but that did not work

Comment: Why don't you write a few lines of code that checks the length...

Comment: [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) has maximum and minimum size properties. Also those are incredibly insecure size restraints for a password

Comment: @GordonAllocman Those size properties are for the graphical dimensions of the visible box.

Answer (score 2):

According to MSDN ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Anchor_2)) within the mask an `a` is used for optional alphanumeric characters, and `A` is used for required alphanumeric characters.

Therefor a mask like the following should work for you:

```
AAAAaaaaaaaaaaa
```

---

EDIT:

So after testing it turns out this doesn't work, as the user is still able to enter texts shorter than 4 characters. So the only real solution I know is to use the `Validating` event to perform the actual verification.

Here is an example for such a event handler implementation for the `Validating` event. I also added an additional check for an empty text-box to prevent the user being "locked" in the text-box when the user didn't enter any value.

```
private void maskedTextBox1_Validating_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    // Stop when empty (avoiding the user getting "locked" in the box)
    if (maskedTextBox1.Text.Length == 0) return;

    // Validate text, cancel when not valid and show error to user
    if (maskedTextBox1.Text.Length < 4 || maskedTextBox1.Text.Length > 15) {
        e.Cancel = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a text of 4 - 15 characters length!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry you're right @LarsTech I should've tested it... it doesn't work as expected :( I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little late, but I'd like to answer this.

For an alphanumeric restriction to have an optional and required number of digits entered, you can use AAAaaaaa. To verify, just check the MaskCompleted and/or the MaskFull properties. MaskCompleted will check if all *required* characters are entered, and MaskFull will check if all *required* and *optional* characters are entered. You do not need to check the length yourself.

So you can do AAAAaaaaaaaaaaa, then check if MaskCompleted is true. If so, they entered at least 4 characters. MaskFull will tell you if they entered a total of 15.